# Why does Tornado set_cookie function always add a pair of quotation marks for cookie's value?

Tags: python, web, tornado

For example, In a Handler, I write:

```
self.set_cookie('name', "value", domain=my_domain)
```

Then I get the value of this cookie in my broswer(Google Chrome), I always get `"value"` instead of `value`.

How can I set cookies without quotation marks surrounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) states, cookie value can be either double-quoted or unquoted at all (see the BNF part of the syntax definition below), and both are valid syntactically, so that's the problem that must be solved on a client-side.

```
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                       ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                       ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                       ; and backslash
token             = <token, defined in [RFC2616], Section 2.2>
```

Cookie version 1 states using double-quoted cookie values for values containing spaces, while cookie version 0 used unquoted values with encoded characters (%20 for spaces), and this behaviour (cookies processing) can differ from browser to browser.